# Sphinx and doxysphinx, how to use doxygen html files BUT not jump around in the navigation panel?

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen, toctree

Just Information:
Try to use Sphinx and doxygen html links together.
I have for example .rst files used in sphinx environment and setting up toctree and stuff.

I have tried to use
:hidden: option for toctree, but that is not working for my purpose cause it just hide it in the content view not in navigation panel.

**Edit**

- doxygen 1.9.5
- Sphinx==6.2.1 sphinx-data-viewer==0.1.2 sphinx-needs==1.2.2 sphinx-rtd-theme==1.2.2 sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.4 sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2 sphinxcontrib-doxylink==1.12.2 sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.0.1 sphinxcontrib-jquery==4.1 sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1 sphinxcontrib-plantuml==0.25 sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3 sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.5

**Added example:::**
Example requested and here is one:

First of all, it doesn't really matter if its an html file or a rst file in the :doc: linking, still refreshes the navigation panel unfortunately.

so the example:
Exists of 4 files:
index.rst
Test.rst
Test4.rst
example.rst

Index.rst:

[image]

Test.rst:

[image]

example.rst:

[image]

Test4.rst:

[image]

So when Clicking the Test22 in demo:

-> [image]

Then I don't want the navigation panel to "lose" the deep or hierarchy as in this pic:

[image]

Any idea how to keep track/depth in the navitagion panel after click :doc: stuff?

Comment: First question is which version of doxygen and sphinx are you using? Second what happens when you just use bare doxygen and navigate around (to see whether it is a doxygen problem or a sphinx problem). Third provide a minimal working example showing the problem.

Comment: Generated by doxygen 1.9.5, will add example soon.

Comment: Sphinx==6.2.1
sphinx-data-viewer==0.1.2
sphinx-needs==1.2.2
sphinx-rtd-theme==1.2.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.4
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-doxylink==1.12.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.0.1
sphinxcontrib-jquery==4.1
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-plantuml==0.25
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.5

Comment: The current doxygen version is 1.10.0 but as far as I know sphinx uses the doxygen xml output so this should not influence the tree behavior as used in the doxygen HTML output.

Comment: May be so yes, probably not the html problem, more of how to include the rst files but not refresh the navigation panel,added example down now.